# What can be done with artifact clothes?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

My fortress has produced an artifact leather coat, leather shirt and gold bracelet. Can these be used for anything except selling them?

For example, could I specify that a dwarf can wear them?

Comment: Have you tried assigning them to a dwarf through the military menu?

Comment: You can't actually sell them, as with all artefacts.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot Artefact is a British spelling; artifact is how the term is spelled in Dwarf Fort.

Comment: I've rolled the edits back to the "artifact" version, let's stick with the game's language to make this question easier to find.

Comment: (Sorry @OrigamiRobot - the revision log confused me. I get it now.)

Comment: @DanRasmussen - No worries.  I actually didn't know artefact was a British spelling.  I saw 'arterfact' and assumed they were all typos.  Yay localized spellcheck!

Comment: @OrigamiRobot I didn't known either, but I've learned the hard way not to be too hasty when calling out typos without Googling the "misspelling" first.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can assign artifact clothing to be worn by a particular dwarf through the military menu. Don't think it works for jewelry.

Artifacts cannot be sold in Fortress mode, but if you put them in containers of sufficient weight (lead, gold and platinum are great for making such containers), the containers will remain in place after abandoning the fortress, allowing you to easily retrieve them with an adventurer. If you install a display case mod (a world regen may be necessary), you can use artifact jewelry and such to boost room value by putting them on display.

Answer (score 1):

Only weapon and armor artifacts can be effectively used by your dwarfs. Clothing and crafted goods artifacts only add to your fortress value.

Comment: I understand that. Still, is there a way to make the dwarves _wear_ the artefacts?

Comment: I'm searching for that information. Until now I've only found something for the [40d version](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/40d:Legendary_artifact#Usage): "Object types which require a dwarf to wear or use the item will generally not be used by your dwarves, with the exception of artifact weapons and armor, which can only be used by heroes and champions." Even if it's outdated, it's possible that it still applies.